# How did these big companies start from these three main points?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

So this is something that Iv'e been thinking about lately, and it basically is : How did big music web apps or websites like Spotify, Youtube, or Anghami(if you know that one) start? I was actually thinking about 3 things, the first : How did they get these huge music libraries? the second : Did each of those big companies need to buy a special server to hold the website data and music Library? and if yes, how much does a special server cost in this case? and the third question is : How did they solve the copyrights with all of these creators or authors or publishers or whatever they're called, the copyrights owners in this case...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** They are uploaded by the artists/creators. I'd imagine pre-release Spotify would have had a library already put together by working with the artists.

**2.** Yes. They cost a lot. There are hundreds of millions of users and terabytes upon terabytes of data, spread around the world. Server costs will be in the millions. Starting out the upfront cost to set up infrastructure would be very high too.

**3.** This is definitely not the place to ask this kind of question. I would Google information on how copyrights with artists usually work